# Temporal autoregression in glmmTMB: what do alternative syntax forms mean?

Tags: r, mixed-model, autocorrelation, glmmtmb

The argument `ar1()` in `glmmTMB` accepts two different forms of syntax (that I know of, there might be others):

1. `ar1(time + 0 | group)`
2. `ar1(time - 1 | group)`

Using one or the other produces the same outcome as far as I can tell, so why are different equivalent forms allowed and what do `- 1` and `+ 0` stand for?
With regards to `- 1`, Ben Bolker [writes](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/corr_braindump.html):

> If we use `ar1(tt|f)`, with `glmmTMB` we get a warning message (“AR1 not
> meaningful with intercept”). This is important; it made me aware of a
> similar mistake I was making previously with my `lmer` hack below. Since
> `lme4` uses unstructured (i.e. general positive-definite)
> variance-covariance matrices by default, it normally doesn’t matter
> how you parameterize the contrasts for a categorical variable – the
> model fit/predictions are invariant to linear transformations. This
> is no longer true when we use structured variance-covariance matrices
> (!), so we need `(tt-1|f)` rather than `(tt|f)` …

This doesn't help me understand, probably because of my lack of understanding of the difference between structured and unstructured variance-covariance matrices.
[Here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/unstructured-covariance-matrix-when-it-does-and-doesn%E2%80%99t-work/) they explain:

> in an unstructured covariance matrix there are no constraints. Each
> variance and each covariance is estimated uniquely from the data. As
> you can imagine, this results in the best possible model fit, because
> each variance and covariance values is very close to what the data
> reflect.
>
> But that comes at a cost that may not be worth the improved fit.
> Estimating each one of those values can use up many degrees of
> freedom.

I guess the follow-up question is "in which way are structured variance-covariance matrices structured?" Besides, I thought that the whole point of assuming an order-1 autoregressive structure in the data was to assume that residuals were autocorrelated in a fixed way ([reference](https://www.flutterbys.com.au/stats/tut/tut8.3a.html)). Doesn't assuming an order-1 autoregressive structure in the data lead to a structured variance-covariance matrix in any case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is still a bit of a mixed bag (even though it has been refined from an earlier Stack Overflow question). However:

- the equivalence of `-1`/`+0` is pure "semantic sugar". Long ago (probably in S, before R was born) the convention was established that intercepts were implicitly included in model formulae, so that e.g. `y ~ x` was exactly equivalent to `y ~ 1 + x` (i.e. $y= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$). Since one sometimes wants to fit a model *without* an intercept, the `-1` syntax was added to allow users to suppress the intercept (i.e. `y ~ -1 + x` corresponds to $y=\beta_1 x$). I *believe* that `+0` was added later as an alternative, possibly more aesthetically pleasing, way to specify a no-intercept model. Because these definitions are built in to base-R's `model.matrix()` function, they are used in a wide variety of R packages. (Today I learned that using `-0` in a formula *adds* an intercept to the model, equivalent to `+1` !)
- the other point is more subtle. In constructing the model for a random effect, R first expands the *effect* (i.e., the `f` in a term like `ar1(f|g)`) into a model matrix. If `f` is a factor, the setup of that model matrix depends on whether an intercept is included in the model or not (and on the *contrasts* associated with the factor). Suppose we have a factor `f <- factor(1:3)`. If the formula is `~f` (and the default *treatment contrasts* are used), the corresponding model matrix is

```
int f2  f3
1   0   0
1   1   0
1   0   1
```

in other words, it is composed of an intercept column (all ones) and $n-1$ *indicator variables* for each level of the factor other than the first. In contrast if we use `~f-1` or `~f+0` the model matrix is

```
f1  f2  f3
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
```

in other words, we have an indicator variable for *every* level (and no intercept).

These two parameterizations are equivalent up to a linear transformation. That means that if we were fitting a regular linear model, or a random effects term with a general/unstructured covariance matrix, then we would get the same *overall* model fit (e.g. the same likelihood, the same model predictions, etc.) even though we would get different sets of estimated parameters (or a different covariance matrix if we were fitting a random effect term); we could transform one vector of parameter estimate, or one covariance matrix, into the other by an appropriate set of linear transformations.

However, because the AR1 covariance matrix represents only a *subset* of all allowable (positive-semidefinite) covariance matrices, it now matters how we parameterize the underlying model matrix.

Comment: Many thanks as always! I wonder if other packages that don't require such specification just do it automatically under the hood. For example `brms` uses the syntax `ar(time = t, gr = g, p = 1, cov = FALSE)`. `ar()` does have a `cov` argument but it only comes into play for ARMA, I don't fully understand what it does but it seems to be addressing something other than the structured/unstructured nature of the matrix.